# Attaching a 24v door bell transformer to a plastic box

Tags: electrical, junction-box, transformer, doorbell, plastic

I am replacing a doorbell transformer, upgrading to 24v because the new doorbell is a Ring doorbell. The existing transformer is 16 volts. It was ganged onto a plastic (on the outside) of a receptible box. It has a what appears to be a 1/2 inch knockout hole on the side which is where the original transformer was attached via a locknut.

Can the new 24v transformer be attached to the existing 1/2 inch knockout hole in the plastic box safely? The new transformer (the only one available) is the screw attachment type not the locknut type. It does not attach snugly as I would prefer, but I think it is installed as designed on the outside of the box.

Comment: Product details or a photo would be helpful. We're all trying to imagine your scenario, and you should _see_ what some of these folks imagine.

Comment: I'll vote for junk the plastic box, replace with steel, don't worry about it failing on you. Dubious that the old setup was actually acceptable. Photo would be very helpful. Please [edit] one in, using the "sun and mountains" icon above the edit box.